# Romulan Empire post Hobus supernova

Tags: star-trek

After the destruction of Romulus by the Hobus supernova did the Romulans find a new homeworld and was the Empire collapsing, causing new factions to rise up?

I know we saw the rise of Nero, but is there anything in-universe,novels,net,etc that tells us what else happens in this period?

Comment: star trek online explores this at depth, the romulans find a new planet, and start to regrow their civilization however they are much diminished and are no longer quite the dominant power they once were. i believe they still are 1 of the 3 "superpowers" in the quadrents but they are by far the weakest at this point since they lost massive amounts of population an di believe other planets not just romulus were destroyed, as well as parts of their fleet.

Comment: STO essentially picks up the main cannon story from the point of the super nova on.

Comment: Worth noting that STO is not considered canon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonically, the last events in the prime timeline we know about are the Hobus Supernova and attempts to contain it, leading to Spock and *Narada*'s displacement in time and forking the *Star Trek* (2009) timeline.

While not canon, *Star Trek Online* has an extensive back-story describing events between the Hobus Supernova (2387) and the beginning of the game (2409), including the political events in the former Romulan Star Empire. While the original "Path to 2409" link appears to no longer exist, the events it described are [summarized on Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Path_to_2409). Several different factions wind up playing a role in the game, including one led by Sela, the half-Romulan daughter of Tasha Yar.

In the Pocket timeline (also, of course, not canonical), prior to the Hobus supernova but after the Dominion War, the Romulans are part of an alliance called the Typhon Pact, which also includes the Tzenkethi Coalition, the Breen Confederacy, the Gorn Hegemony, and the Tholian Assembly. This alliance  stands in opposition to the Khitomer Accord governments (primarily the Federation and the Klingon Empire).

This time line has not yet caught up with the Hobus Supernova (the most recent novels taking place, according to [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Memory_Beta_Chronology:_2380s), in 2386), but already contradict *Star Trek Online* in one major regard (unrelated to the Romulans but still spoilerish):

> Pocket's novels assume that *Terok Nor*, the original Deep Space 9, was destroyed by terrorist action in 2383 (the novels *Plagues of Night* and *Raise the Dawn*) and replaced by a unique Federation-designed station (as opposed to a standard starbase) shortly thereafter (*Raise the Dawn* and *Revelations and Dust*). *Star Trek Online* continues to assume that the original *Terok Nor*/DS9 is intact. It's a major venue in the game, acting as a social hub until recent game changes saw it taken over by a rogue Dominion force.

Comment: Would the Treaty of Algeron still be in place?

Comment: As.a matter of pure speculatuon, I would say it would depend on whether the Federation recognized any particular faction as the legal successor, and hence,  continuing treaty partner. Otherwise, without another side to it, the treaty could be said to be void. I don't believe STO answers the question.